# Memory issue: dalvikvm-heap: Out of memory on a xxxxx-byte allocation

Tags: titanium, titanium-mobile, titanium-alloy

I get the below memory error when opening a heavyweight window which contains a tableview.

It's okay for the first 10-15 times its opened/closed but after that I keep getting the below:

```
I/dalvikvm-heap(22638): Forcing collection of SoftReferences for 5030656-byte allocation
D/dalvikvm(22638): GC_BEFORE_OOM freed <1K, 10% free 116152K/128624K, paused 91ms, total 91ms
E/dalvikvm-heap(22638): Out of memory on a 5030656-byte allocation.
```

[Full stack-trace here](https://gist.github.com/Tam2/9aaf94adbd6bfabd760a)

Whenever I close the window, I use the below code:

```
    $.Storyboard.close();
    $.destroy();
```

Is this something that I'm doing wrong or is there an issue with Titanium?

I'm running Titanium 3.1.3GA, with Alloy

Comment: Is destroy() your own method? It is undocumented, isn't it? What is its purpose?

Comment: @mwfire - it is a documented method http://docs.appcelerator.com/titanium/3.0/#!/api/Alloy.Controller-method-destroy

Answer (score 0):

Please try changing the code in your controller to:

```
$.Storyboard.close();

$.Storyboard.addEventListener('close', function() {
    $.destroy();
});
```

destroy() might get called too late outside an event listener.

Comment: I've moved my `$.destroy()` into an eventlistener as you've said above but I'm still getting the same issue.

I can see that when the destroy event is called it [logs a message](https://gist.github.com/Tam2/fa0973457a905949fbfd).

I've also uploaded my code if you want to [take a look HERE](https://gist.github.com/Tam2/f83796aedec9da7a65f7)

Answer (score 0):

You are only supposed to use the `destroy` function if you are uing model-view binding, (from your code, looks like you are not).

`destroy` removes event listeners attached to your controller that have references to global  models and collections (which prevents memory leaks), when you close the window you have already destroyed any such references (but mostly since your not using model-view binding).

So don't call `$.destroy` at all.

Comment: Ah thanks, but with/without `$.destory` I'm still getting the memory warnings. The window opens up fine, and other items in the window are there, the only thing that fails to load is the tableview

Comment: Are you setting `Alloy.Globals.Device` somewhere? Ti.API.info() your $.table.width, or debug through it. Also, f thats the case then your memory errors are not coming from  destroy().

Comment: Yes its being set in alloy.js, the `Alloy.Globals.Device` seems to work fine as I'm using it throughout the app to determine width/height of elements. The issue seems to be when the tableview is trying to render on the view

Comment: Well you have some weird things going on, for instance your nesting a TableView in a ScrollView (bad bad practice), you have a global controller function that relies on previously instantiated data (getStoryBoard), and you use appendRow after the table has been created, any one of these things could cause problems, including rendering issues and memory leaks.